# Gradle: How to init SourceTask's property ‘source’ with extension property?

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

My plugin registers an extension and some custom task that inherited from `org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceTask`.

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    private final Instantiator instantiator
    private final FileResolver fileResolver
    @Inject
    MyPlugin (Instantiator instantiator, FileResolver fileResolver) {
        this.instantiator = instantiator
        this.fileResolver = fileResolver
    }
    void apply(Project project) {
        MyPluginExtension extension = project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyPluginExtension, project, instantiator, fileResolver)
        project.tasks.create('doSomething', MyCustomTask) {}
    }
}

class MyPluginExtension {
    final MySourceSetContainer source
    MyPluginExtension(Project project, Instantiator instantiator, FileResolver fileResolver) {
        source = instantiator.newInstance(ImplMySourceSetContainer, project, instantiator, fileResolver)
    }
    void source(Closure closure) {
        ConfigureUtil.configure(closure, source)
    }
}

class MyCustomTask extends SourceTask {
    @TaskAction
    void act() {
        // something
    }
}
```

And now, if I configure build script:

> ```
> myPlugin {
>     source{
>         main {
>             something {
>                 srcDirs "src/main/resources"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> doSomething {
>     source = myPlugin.source.main.something.asFileTree
> }
> ```

- All works fine. But I want to initialize task property `source` by value from `MyPluginExtension`.

`source = extension.source.findAll().inject(project.files().asFileTree, { result, item -> result + item.html.asFileTree })`

I can't extract extension property at the execution phase as it described in the userguide (https://docs.gradle.org/4.2.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:mapping_extension_properties_to_task_properties), because getter for `source` that declared in superclass `org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceTask` marked with annotation `@org.gradle.api.tasks.SkipWhenEmpty` and task will be skipped.

How can I initialize task's property with value from extension before execution phase?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by wrapping source init in closure:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    // ...
    void apply(Project project) {
        MyPluginExtension extension = project.extensions.create("myPlugin", MyPluginExtension, project, instantiator, fileResolver)
        project.tasks.create('doSomething', MyCustomTask) { task ->
            task.source = { 
                extension.source.findAll().inject(new HashSet<File>(), { result, item -> result + item.html.srcDirs }) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you are doing but you could likely use a closure to delay evaluation. See [Project.files(Object...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files(java.lang.Object...))

Eg:

```
doSomething {
    def myClosure = {
        extension.source.findAll().inject(project.files().asFileTree, { result, item -> result + item.html.asFileTree })
    }
    source = files(myClosure)
}
```

Comment: I want to get `source` value from extension named 'myPlugin' (type `MyPluginExtension`), extract FileTree object, and set it for task property (`MyCustomTask.source`).